# set created input text selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following label:

```
<div id="email">
  <label>
    myemail@gmail.com
  </label>
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</div>

<div id="phone">
  <label>
    1234567890
  </label>
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</div>
```

When I click on the edit button I want to replace the label with an input and set the label value as selected. Below is what i have tried so far:

```
$('.fa-edit').click(function(){
var info = $(this).closest('div');
var label = info.find('label');
var curr_value = label.text();
label.replaceWith('<input class="edit_input" type="text" value="'+curr_value+'" />')
  .focus(function(){
     //alert(this);
     this.select();
  });
// some code ..
```

the problem is that I can not set the input text as selected (ready to be replaced).
What should I do?

Comment: there could be several selector sharing the same class.so I need to address `this` input !!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrezasaberi/nq3838z8/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the input element and set the focus & select on it after you replace the label.

Please check the below code:

```js
$("#editBtn").click(function(){
   var label = $(this).parent().find('label');
   var curr_value = label.text().trim();
   
   var newInput = $('<input class="edit_input" type="text" value="'+curr_value+'" />')
   
   label.replaceWith(newInput)
   newInput.focus().select()
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="email">
  <label>
    myemail@gmail.com
  </label>
  <button id="editBtn">EDIT</button>
</div>
```

Comment: there could be several selector sharing the same class. wont be that a problem?

Comment: i updated my answer with a better approach without using a class selector

Comment: can you please clarify? refresh the page and try the snippet - upon clicking of the email label it turns into input and it's content is selected

Comment: i updated the example using the EDIT button (  you can replace it with your icon)

Comment: It does replace the label but does not select the code, test your answer here: https://jsfiddle.net/ifinto/o2gxgz9r/

Comment: your jsfiddle  contains completely irrelevant code. What browser are you using?

Comment: Try this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/19767/ , tested in both chrome and firefox and works as expected

Answer (score 1):

the value returned from .replaceWith is still the old `<label />` reference, you need to re-select the input, so that you can focus it.

```
label.replaceWith('<input class="edit_input" type="text" value="'+curr_value+'" />')
$('.edit_input').off('focus').on('focus',function() {
    this.select()
}).trigger('focus')
```

use off() to remove previous event listener everytime the user click the edit button again.

Comment: @Saberi focus([Funtion]) just bind the event listener to the input, need to trigger the focus event after bind it

Answer (score 0):

i hope that help you.

```
var label = $('label');
var curr_value = label.text();
label.replaceWith('<input class="edit_input" type="text" value="'+curr_value+'" />').focus(function(){
     $(this).select(); });
```

Comment: i edited the code. i set select just for that repalced input

Comment: No that didn't help Mohamed